# Video transfer using Ethernet from Raspberry pi to another Ubuntu system at controlled data rate

Tags: ubuntu, streaming

I have a video stored on Raspberry Pi card in h.264 format. This video has to be transferred at controlled data rate to another computer using ethernet cable upon request by other computer. I think that this can be accomplished using socket programming and rtsp. But I am stuck with the following two points:

1. How is the already stored video problem different from live video streaming?
2. How to control the data rates?
3. Is there anything special about packetization of h.264 packets?

Comment: Welcome to Unix+Linux, WhiteHorse. This could be a duplicate of http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/12156/is-it-possible-to-stream-h-264-with-rtsp-on-raspberry-pi ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Live video streaming has to deal with transmission errors, random access/resycnhronisation and ff/rew in very different ways than reading a local file might allow. Also, if by "video" you actually meant "an audio+video bundle", then there is the problem of interleaving the A and V, and the related problems of clocking and lip-sync.
2. If a probabalistic solution is good enough, and the source is capable of "over pumping", then creating a bit-rate controlled file transfer program client (e.g. for FTP) is straightforward. Otherwise you may need to solve the somewhat more tricky problem of a bitrate controlled pump.
3. It all depends on what your file actually contains. You might for example mean an ISO 13818-1 Transport Stream containing H.264 part 10 video and ISO 11172-3 audio: then the packets in the file would be 188 byte Transport Stream packets. You could equally mean an actual H.264 file which does not have a packet structure in the sense you likely mean. The good news is that if all you need is file transfer, then any such file packetisation format is pretty much irrelevant: just use whatever your file protocol wants to use. Note: RTSP is used to set up streaming sessions, not to actually transfer the data, and so is likely irrelevant to your problem.